# How to write a unit test for IndexError in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert

I have a function `generate_grid(n, dices)` that takes into parameters n and dices, generates a grid of size n-by-n. In my unit tests, I wish to make sure that if I call `generate_grid(-4, Dices)`, It is going to produce `IndexError: list index out of range`. But how to do it ?

I tried to assert the followingl;
`assert(generate_grid(-4, Des)) == 'IndexError: list index out of range'`
but the assertion doesn't work and the program stops

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using? They usually have asserts for exceptions, and the documentation should show you how to use it. e.g [**`assertRaises`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)